# Add default value to an already created column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 3.2.6 app and I need to add a default value to a column on an already created table called tasks. How can I do this with a migration?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a alter migration with default value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options = {})`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column):

```
def up
  change_column :tasks, :my_column, :integer, :default => 1
end
```